Batch script cannot locate configuration file, and the file is there
Below is the batch script I've been working on, however, I cannot move past locating the configuration file from which the script is parsing. When I run the script I get an error message that System cannot find the file D:\WKGPDATA\INFOtrac\Conduit\Conduit.ini
@echo off
REM Disable command echo for cleaner output.

REM Function to compare LastScanUTC time stamp with current UTC time.
:CompareTime
setlocal

REM Get the LastScanUTC time stamp from the configuration file.
for /f "usebackq tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ("D:\WKGPDATA\INFOtrac\Conduit\Conduit.ini") do (
    set LastScanUTC=%%a
)

REM snipped all unrelated lines here

endlocal
goto :EOF

It is supposed to read the LastScanUTC timestamp from the configuration file located at "D:\WKGPDATA\INFOtrac\Conduit", and assign it to the variable LastScanUTC.

@VladimirInosavljevic, I specifically asked you to 'include other very important information about the environment in which this script is being run, and how it is being invoked, (Scheduled Task; with elevation; as another User etc.), as well as information about the stated volume D:', not just changing the path to the ini file. I expected, due to the time taken, and that you were 'Working on it', that you would have actually made an effort to submit that information. If we cannot reproduce your environment, code, and how it is being run, we cannot assist you in fixing it, without guessing!

Hi All, the script started to work. Thank you all for your help.
